# Average of middle number

Tags: average

I was doing a question on average and the question was that - If the average of 1st 12 number is 10.8, average of 1st 6 number is 10.4 and the last 6 number is 11.5. Find the 6th number.
Now according to me i thought the number which is the middle one is counted twice but the actual solution subtracts the sum of last and 1st 6 number sum and subtracts with the sum of 12 numbers.
Can anyone help me why is it correct and does it not double counts the middle number twice?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of $12$ numbers, the first six numbers are in positions $1-6$ and the last six numbers are in positions $7-12$.  As stated, the data you are given is inconsistent with the list being $12$ numbers.  If the first six average $10.4$ and the last six average $11.5$, the whole list would have to average $10.95$.  Please check the problem and state it clearly.